# ASP.NET Core MVC : BadRequest(exception) not getting caught at ErrorController

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am facing one issue on ASP.NET Core MVC side. I have set following code in configuration:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Errors/Error");               
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/Error/{0}");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/Error/{0}");
app.UseHsts();
```

When I am catching the exception via a `try/catch` block as follows:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{              
    return BadRequest();                  
}
```

This code works perfectly, and exception is passed on to the ErrorController.

But instead of using `return BadRequest()`, if I write `return BadRequest(ex)`, then it is not getting caught in the `ErrorController`.

In that case the exception details is displayed on client side as follows

[image]

I'm not entirely sure why? Can you please explain?

Comment: you use try/catch block in every API? why not use a middleware or filter to do this

Comment: Sounds good. will try with exceptionfilter and/or errormiddleware